# Sample selection from within a certain area

Tags: geometry, sampling-theory

I need to make a random selection of mosques in a large city for a public health survey.  I have a map that identifies a thousand of them, but many are unmapped, so I don't know what my 'universe' is, so I can't get a random sample.  I'm considering dividing up the city into sections of equal area, taking a sample of those areas, and walking them to map missing mosques. Then I'll do a random selection of mosques from among the ones in my sample areas.  Question 1) Have I gone off the rails so far?

To save on shoe leather, I would prefer to select fewer, larger areas in preference to more, smaller ones.  Question 2) How few areas can I get away with, and still have a enough to keep critics quiet?

Thank for any help you can offer.

Comment: There's no way to pull coordinate data from a site like Google maps?

Comment: Elaborating on question #2 in response to a comment that has since disapeared: Into how many areas must I divide my geography before I can take a sample of areas within which to complete my identification of mosques, if I want the mosques in those sample areas to serve as the basis for a random selection for survey purposes?

Comment: Re coordinate data from a site like Google maps:  Yes, I can deal with a range of GIS packages.  The mosques I have identified so far are from Google Maps.

Comment: I am trying to apply Cochran's formula to set my sample size after I have divided up the study area, but I can't figure out how to set my confidence interval, the margin of error number.  Once I have my areas selected, we will survey them to know what mosques they contain.  There is no attribute around which to have a margin of error, as far as I can see. Once we have a representative list of mosques, we will do a selection from it for the actual survey.  How else might I set my area sample size? 
 Forgive me if this is too obscure.  Thanks.